# The movement's ideas are not merely absurd; they are ... dangerous

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Which option fits best for the following sentence.

> The movement's ideas are not merely absurd; they are ... dangerous.
>
> 1.Formally
>
> 2.Perfectly
>
> 3.Absolutely
>
> 4.Positively

For me 1,2 and 3 work .